# creating a tag-based website and not using programming?

Tags: development, database, web-development, education

I want to create a tag-based website, and I need a tool that I could use (preferably without programming).

It's a site where a user could pick tags on a certain item. All tags will be placed under a group that they are logically linked to (I will do that by hand). On the other end - a visitor could choose a tag, and then be redirected to a few items on which that tag was selected the most. Besides this, I need to set up a registration form (for the visitors who want to select tags on a desired item).

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) may serve as an example of what I want to achieve. Functionally it is a quite similar approach. I am not sure if further detailing will bring me closer to getting a development advice, but nevertheless - following this template what I would be missing on is:

- ability to categorize the tags; and so they would fit in one page (overall i assume <200 tags)
- box where a user could enter a tag and it would be pending until a certain number of users enter such tag
- ability to limit the number of 'questions' that appear when a visitor chooses a tag - 'question' stands for an item to which users are selecting tags (displayed items would depend on the frequency the tag was assigned - say the top two items)

Which software should I try / How should I go about it?

P.S. I have bought hosting account through GoDaddy.com. This is a first website that I am trying to build.

Comment: You might want to also ask this on webapps, its conceivable that someone has come up with a hosted tagging solution for static sites. Actually, it would not be that difficult, and could be monetized via sponsored tags.

Answer (score 3):

Practically any modern CMS offers what you are asking for - [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/), [Drupal](http://drupal.org/), [Joolma](http://www.joomla.org/), etc.

The limits for tags on a page are mostly editable - although the question elements needs elaborated for any further help (there are plugins for the three CMS's mentioned above that cover this). If it is a community focused site and you like the stackoverflow way of doing things why not post your suggestion on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: As for community focus - even though I am OK to let this thing go and grow naturally, by having a trust in the contents of 'defining what’s on- and off-topic', it won't do it as the concept is not around ones expertise, but ones opinion - reflection on experiences. The question element is to be seen as an object on which a user expresses his/her opinion. There will be a need to define the object by a one sentence description and place a picture to it. In a sense it's like brandtags.net/index.php, just ~ other way around.

Comment: Aha - then a commenting solution - like those found in nearly all CMS's would seem the best option. You can customise the word "comment" to "opinion".

Comment: this Drupal service looks hardcore, I am now trying to get into it. So what you are saying is that such CMS solution may be all I need to build, and later manage, this site? / Are there any sure downsides that I could face in the long-run? .. As I said, it is the first website that I am building on my own. I have yet no programming experience; once I was managing the content of a company website that I was working in - I don't remember anymore which CMS it was, but I am quite sure that program was not used to build a website itself, and that is why I am rather confused in this whole process..

Comment: Any CMS will have its times of need. Wordpress for instance have just released version 3 - although many have managed to setup their own servers and the upgrade should have gone smoothly there will always be woes somewhere.

Comment: Man, This is not helping me out! ;) P.S. the change of the word comment to the word option you suggested above will doubtfully do it for me, as I need all responses to be indexed, and if I am following you correctly commenting solution refers to a textual information that doesn't go together with the pre-phrased tags. By saying that 'the question element is to be seen as an object on which a user expresses his/her opinion', I meant that the users choice of a tag is The expressed opinion. Still at zero point.

Comment: Aha - so you post a question and people pick a pre-selected tag based on this? You want want to try http://polldaddy.com/ or any poll plugin for your CMS of choice. Just pre-create the tags as options. If you need the user to create tags of their own then this becomes more specialist and I am unable to help.

Comment: Nope, users won't be creating tags on their own - they have an option to suggest a tag if they lack one. And so you say to choose CMS and try such plugin to it? But that involves programing, doesn't it?..

Comment: No programming needed. For instance my web host allows for installing WordPress in a single click. Then login to the admin section and select plugins - add one like this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-polls/ and it will install without even opening a text file ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that, unless you have only a small number of possible tags (i.e. ~20) that you don't try to do this by hand. You could conceivably do it on a small static shopping cart, for instance, for people to have something a little more intuitive to use to see similar products. Maintaining that by hand would not be too difficult.

There is no way, however, that I would want to manually update static 'tag' pages every time something new was introduced.

If you didn't want to involve a database, you could conceivably use `rel` descriptors strategically so that something could read all of your pages and auto generate the 'tag' pages .. but then we're still getting into programming.

Basically, any way you look at it, you're looking at some programming (or using a CMS of some sort that features tagging). You'd probably need to make further modifications to get the color / limiting features that you want.

It is conceivable that someone has come up with a way to offer customized tagging as a service (similar to those who offer hosted comment areas), but I've yet to see one.

Comment: Thing is that products are not related in terms of ones experience of a single product. Let's say we have Milk, and we have Grapes. User comes by to express his opinion on Milk, and he finds the same tags that he can use to do so as a user that tried Grapes does - enjoyable, disturbing, inspiring...

And there is the other end, where a visitor pics up a Tag (or a few, or a whole category (that tags are placed under)), and 
then he is linked to a Product(s) (based on the top tag count).

Besides this - registration form, entering a new Product, suggesting a Tag. It's more of a service-type site